# Wrong/unexpected Values obtained from Powerlaw fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to curve fit a power law to my data using the power law distribution.This is the sample data from which I am extracting values and then trying to curve fit into the data extracted. [Sampledata](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qrutcnesqyqe93c/AAAfpcapImO8XEQhTKeeSaRDa?dl=0). The sample data contains a single text file & from this file I am extracting two columns of data. I want to curve fit a power law into this data and obtain the coefficients A and B from Y = A*(X^B). I expect a negative value of B as it is a decreasing curve.

SOLVED: I used a Scipy Optimize curve fit. This is the code that works. Hope it helps somebody.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
###############################################################################
def centerline1(V1,Y1):
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = plt.subplot()
    ax.plot(Y1,V1)
    plt.hold(True)
    ax.set_xlabel('Y (m)')
    ax.set_ylabel('V_center/V_nozzle')
    ax.set_title('Plane Jet')
    ax.legend(['ddn110A'],loc =0)
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.figtext(0.6,0.40,"Flow Time = 50s",style= 'normal',alpha=0.5)                   

flowtime1 = input('Enter the flowtime for ddn110A: ')
flowtime2 = input('Enter the flowtime for ddn110B: ')

FT_init1 = 3.61
delt = 0.15
TS_init1 = 150
V_initial =0.236
b_O = 0.6096
timestep1 = (flowtime1-FT_init1)/delt
timestep1 = int(round(timestep1 + TS_init1))
timestepstring1=str(timestep1).zfill(4)

path1 = "path"
fname1 = path1+"c1-"+timestepstring1+".txt"
f1 = open(fname1,'r')
data1 = np.loadtxt(f1,skiprows=1)
V1 = data1[:,4]
V1 = V1/(V_initial)
firstIdx = np.nonzero(V1==V1.min())[0][0]
Y1 = data1[:,2]  # Assigning Y to column 5 from the text file
Y1 = Y1/(b_O) # Dividing Y by bo which is the half width
s = (2*1.2192)
Y1 = Y1[s:firstIdx]
V1= V1[s:firstIdx]
centerline1(V1,Y1)
#################################################################
def func1(x,C,m):
   return C*np.array((x**m))
xdata1 = Y1
ydata1 = V1
popt1,pcov1 =curve_fit(func1,xdata1,ydata1,p0=[5,-1]) ## (Optimize Curve Fit from Scipy)
perr1 = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov1))
```

Comment: Your code is quite extensive for debugging. Please consider constructing a [mcve]. And I also suggest plotting your data and your fit, it would be clear whether the fit is right or wrong. And finally, I suggest avoiding the use of `from scipy import *`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I edited the code to make it compact and minimal. I removed the code for case 2. Now the code contains the logic only for case. I have also removed the from scipy imports as it was not being used at all. Can you please let me know how to plot the fit along with my data? I am not sure if I am doing the fit correctly or not. Thank you for your time

Comment: Much better, thanks:) I realized that the ploting is not trivial: you'd have to plot the resulting fit together with a histogram computed from your data...  Although I don't understand a few things: [`scipy.stats.powerlaw`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powerlaw.html) seems to have a `fit` method, not a `Fit` one; and the call to `centerline1` doesn't seem to be a call at all...

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am so sorry about the centerline1 function call. I fixed the code now. I am pretty new to Stack Overflow. So I apologize if my question was not properly posted. I have added a link to the power law package in the question that I used in my code. I would appreciate your advice on this.  Thank you.

Comment: It's OK, many new users mess up their questions (and most of them don't even mind:). Unfortunately, I'm not at all familiar with this custom package. If its help/manual doesn't help you, I also won't be able to.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I have no particular inclination to use this custom package. I can use scipy.stats.powerlaw scheme as well. If you could show me how to modify my code so that I can verify if the fit is proper or not by using scipy scheme, I would be really grateful.

Comment: I would compute a histogram with either [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram) or [`scipy.stats.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.histogram.html), then plot together the histogram with the `pdf` of your fitted powerlaw.

Comment: Please be aware that "it did not work" is never sufficient information in any case. If you expect any help, and that is probably the reason why you're on Stack Overflow, then be more specific: do you get a wrong result? Do you get an error? What kind of errror?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I apologize for my previous comment. I wanted to write about the error, but pressed enter by mistake. When I plot the pdf curve, it   is showing a sharp gradient. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Could you please show me how to implement scipy.stats.powerlaw for my code?

Comment: It's OK. You can edit your comments in the first 5 minutes after posting using the "edit" link appearing when you hover your mouse above the comment. I'll try to come up with a short snippet, but in the mean time, please consider posting an update to your question, with the image of where you are currently at.